# First time getting Django/WSGI running, having some issues

Tags: python, django, configuration, apache2, wsgi

I've got Python installed ok, I can run scripts at the command line just fine. But I want to build web pages with it, and use the Django framework.

I've read through lots of documentation on how to setup and get django running.
Most of the work was done with apt-get install, which did install everything needed, but the vhost configuration I am having trouble with. Currently I am getting a 500 Server error and in the error log I am seeing an Import error.

Here's the full vhost file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin richtestani@mac.com
        ServerName friendflix.me
                ServerAlias www.friendflix.me
        DocumentRoot "/srv/www/friendflix.me/public_html/"
        ErrorLog /srv/www/friendflix.me/logs/error.log
            CustomLog /srv/www/friendflix.me/logs/access.log combined

            WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/friendflix.me/application/django.wsgi
      <Directory /srv/www/friendflix.me/application>
 Order allow,deny
Allow from all
  </Directory>

    <Location "/application">
SetHandler python-program
  PythonOption django.root /application
  PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
PythonPath "['/srv/www/friendflix.me/application', '/srv/www/friendflix.me/publ$
PythonDebug On
</Location>

Alias /static /srv/www/friendflix.me/public_html/static
</VirtualHost>
```

Tail of error.log

```
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]     self.load_middleware() 
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]     self._setup()
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Sun Jun 19 21:28:07 2011] [error] [client 74.89.144.194] ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

Directory structure of app (or at least)

html root

```
/srv/www/friendflix.me/public_html
```

application root

```
/srv/www/friendflix.me/application
```

Django/wsgi application config

```
/srv/www/friendflix.me/application/django.wsgi
```

Django.wsgi script

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/friendflix.me/application')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/friendflix.me/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Any help in to fix this would be great - thank you!
Rich

Comment: Can you please post the details of the import error?

Comment: Your configuration got truncated.

Comment: please post the directory structure of your app

Comment: Please include your `django.wsgi` script.  It doesn't have a proper setting for `sys.path`.

Comment: Why do you have configurations for both mod_wsgi **and** mod_python? That's bound to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> *The value of* ***DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE*** *should be in Python path syntax, e.g. **mysite.settings***
>    <sub>[**designating-the-settings**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings)</sub> 
>    <sub>[**modpython basic-configuration**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/?from=olddocs#basic-configuration)</sub>

So if your project (site) name is `application`:

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE application.settings
```

Comment: So in my situation, my site name is application or friendflix.me? What actually defined this name?

Comment: `mysite` should actually be the name of your django project => the package under which is located `settings.py` => The name of the folder where lives your `settings.py`.